# Reactjs and Firebase: one login interface for user and admin or separate login interface?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm doing a school project using reactjs and Firestore that has 2 users; user and admin. These are the features:

User:
User registers on the website. Upon registration, the system will generate a QR code for the user to be scanned. Upon scanning, the vaccination status of the user will be updated such as the vaccine type, dose, date of vaccination, and etc. The user may also input side effects they've experienced, and view the vaccination graph reports.

Admin:
Admin can log in and scan the qr code, view vaccination graph reports, Vaccine (CRUD), list of the users

- Is it okay to have one login interface for both users and admin? Are there any security risk or defining the security rules is already enough?
- Or is it preferable to have a separate login interface? If a separate login interface will
  be used, would I need Firebase Admin SDK and Cloud Functions (the problem here is that we do not have a credit card for the Cloud functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are executing the QR Code logic for both admin and users and fetching all these details. Nonetheless, I would like to suggest an approach that you can follow. You can set your authentication based on role and create multiple routes for your application using React Router for Firebase.

- For instance, a user should be able to visit a public landing page,
  and also use sign up and sign in pages to enter the application as an
  authenticated user. If a user is authenticated, it is possible to
  visit protected pages like account or admin pages whereas the latter
  is only accessible by authenticated users with an admin role.
- There is no reason to show a non authenticated user the account or
  home page in the first place, because these are the places where a
  user accesses sensitive information. In this section, you will
  implement a protection for these routes called authorization. The
  protection is a broad-grained authorization, which checks for
  authenticated users. If none is present, it redirects from a
  protected to a public route; else, it will do nothing. The condition
  is defined as:

> const condition = authUser => authUser != null;
> // short version 
> const condition = authUser => !!authUser; 
> In contrast, a more fine-grained authorization could be a role-based or permission-based authorization 
> // role-based authorization
> const condition = authUser => authUser.role === 'ADMIN'; 
> // permission-based authorization 
> const condition = authUser => authUser.permissions.canEditAccount;

The real authorization logic happens in the componentDidMount() lifecycle method. Like the withAuthentication() higher-order component, it uses the Firebase listener to trigger a callback function every time the authenticated user changes. The authenticated user is either an authUser object or null.. If the authorization fails, for instance because the authenticated user is null, the higher-order component redirects to the sign in page. If it doesn't fail, the higher-order component does nothing and renders the passed component (e.g. home page, account page).
You can check this [tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial) and get an idea of the approach I was mentioning.

Just a reminder : While Firebase Realtime Database can be used on the free plan, Cloud Firestore is charged by usage. That's why you can set monthly quotas and [budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets). You can always see the pricing plan, and adjust it, in the bottom left corner of your Firebase project's dashboard.
Also yes Cloud Functions still has a monthly free allowance that's documented in the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). But you will have to provide a credit card and be on a billing plan in order to use it. You will be responsible for paying for any monthly overage. But I don’t think you will need Cloud functions for that matter, just some decent db rules to protect your database and the authentication of your application based on role and routes using React Router for Firebase should be good enough.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take it into consideration. I just want to ask if this is an appropriate approach for the QR code logic. Upon registration of the user, they will have a QR code that stores their userID . So on the admin's side, they would be able to scan the QR code of the user. On implementing this on the admin side, I would be able to retrieve the userID of the user and using useEffects I could retrieve the details of the scanned user. Is this approach alright?

Comment: Yeah now I get it. The idea looks good to me. One question though, you mentioned that admin scans the QR Code of the user and gets the information, my question will be how you are storing the QR Code of the users.

Comment: My understanding/ suggestion would be , when a user registers through the app, QR code gets generated which stores the UID of the user and all information that user has input in the registration form is uploaded to the database. Now the admin can login and the admin page should have the  list of the users, with their information and UID being the key. Then they can expand the document for the particular UID and can see all the information.  Correct me if I am misunderstanding your point somewhere.

Comment: I think it's quite the same. Since after the user will register, they will be asked to update their personal information which will then be saved in the database. In the admin's side, when the admin scans the QR code, the UID will be retrieved and a useEffects will be used with something like .doc(scanResult), scanResult is the variable name for the retrieved UID from the scanned QR code, then the user information can be displayed on the admin's screen. The admin will also have a list of users.

Comment: Yes just that you have to generate unique QR Codes for each user. I think the approach is alright and looks good to me as you described it. Also if my answer helped you, please make sure you vote/ accept it. Thanks and All the best!

Comment: Hello again, I would like to ask some questions. Since I'll be storing the date of the 1st and 2nd dose of vaccine of the users. In what format of the date should I store it to ensure there's a dynamic reporting per month? I've also asked this in stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68781277/in-what-date-format-should-i-store-in-the-firestore-to-create-a-dynamic-report-o