# In what date format should I store in the Firestore to create a dynamic report of per month?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I have a project to store the vaccination status of the users such as their 1st dose and 2nd dose. I would like to create a dynamic graph reporting for each of the vaccines.  And I am planning to create a dynamic reporting per month and year and my database is a Firestore.

Similar to this kind of graph:

[image]

Since I will be storing the dates for the user's 1st dose and 2nd dose, in what date format should I store it to ensure a dynamic report. Also, for the graph, I will be using chart.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO strings are both human readable and sortable:

```
const date = new Date();
date.toISOString();
// => "2021-08-14T08:01:29.134Z"
```

If you don’t need readability, epoch time probably better for DB disk space:

```js
const date = new Date();
date.getTime();
// => 1628928089134
// OR
Date.now();
// => 1628928089134
```

In both cases you can use the returned values to re-create the date object and get the month and year to use for filtering and analysis.

```js
const recreatedDate = new Date("2021-08-14T08:01:29.134Z");
// alternatively:
// const recreatedDate = new Date(1628928089134);

// January is month number 0
console.log(recreatedDate.getMonth() + 1);
// => 8

console.log(recreatedDate.getFullYear());
// => 2021
```

Comment: Would it work in a dynamic reporting of per month and year?

Comment: I see no reason why not. What is your concern?